# Spring Cloud Contract - Messaging - NoSuchBeanDefinitionException during contract verification on producer side

Tags: rabbitmq, messaging, amqp, spring-cloud-contract

executing 'mvn clean install' on producer side i get the error message.
According to logs the connection to the stub is established.
The next step verifying the contract throws an exception.

## Contract

```
label: user-goes-online
input:
  triggeredBy: onUserIsOnline()
outputMessage:
  sentTo: user-presence
  body:
    user: amadeus
  headers:
    contentType: application/json
```

https://github.com/nusmanov/producer/blob/master/src/test/resources/contracts/user-presence.yaml

## Code

- Producer: https://github.com/nusmanov/producer
- Consumer: https://github.com/nusmanov/consumer

## Full Log

```
 mvn clean install                                                                                                                                      nodirbekusmanov@CFC02XL862JG5H
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] --------------------------< com.cdt:producer >--------------------------
[INFO] Building producer 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-osgi:jar:2.2.10 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (default-clean) @ producer ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/nodirbekusmanov/workspace/poc-consumer/2/producer/target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources (default-resources) @ producer ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ producer ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to /Users/nodirbekusmanov/workspace/poc-consumer/2/producer/target/classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin:2.2.2.RELEASE:generateTests (default-generateTests) @ producer ---
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7$1 (file:/Users/nodirbekusmanov/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/2.5.9/groovy-2.5.9.jar) to constructor java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup(java.lang.Class,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[INFO] Generating server tests source code for Spring Cloud Contract Verifier contract verification
[INFO] Will use contracts provided in the folder [/Users/nodirbekusmanov/workspace/poc-consumer/2/producer/src/test/resources/contracts]
[INFO] Directory with contract is present at [/Users/nodirbekusmanov/workspace/poc-consumer/2/producer/src/test/resources/contracts]
[INFO] Test Source directory: /Users/nodirbekusmanov/workspace/poc-consumer/2/producer/target/generated-test-sources/contracts added.
[INFO] Using [com.cdt.producer.TestBase] as base class for test classes, [null] as base package for tests, [null] as package with base classes, base class mappings []
[INFO] Creating new class file [/Users/nodirbekusmanov/workspace/poc-consumer/2/producer/target/generated-test-sources/contracts/com/cdt/producer/ContractVerifierTest.java]
[INFO] Generated 1 test classes.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin:2.2.2.RELEASE:convert (default-convert) @ producer ---
[INFO] Will use contracts provided in the folder [/Users/nodirbekusmanov/workspace/poc-consumer/2/producer/src/test/resources/contracts]
[INFO] Copying Spring Cloud Contract Verifier contracts to [/Users/nodirbekusmanov/workspace/poc-consumer/2/producer/target/stubs/META-INF/com.cdt/producer/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/contracts]. Only files matching [.*] pattern will end up in the final JAR with stubs.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Converting from Spring Cloud Contract Verifier contracts to WireMock stubs mappings
[INFO]      Spring Cloud Contract Verifier contracts directory: /Users/nodirbekusmanov/workspace/poc-consumer/2/producer/src/test/resources/contracts
[INFO] Stub Server stubs mappings directory: /Users/nodirbekusmanov/workspace/poc-consumer/2/producer/target/stubs/META-INF/com.cdt/producer/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/mappings
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ producer ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/nodirbekusmanov/workspace/poc-consumer/2/producer/target/generated-test-resources/contracts
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ producer ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to /Users/nodirbekusmanov/workspace/poc-consumer/2/producer/target/test-classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) @ producer ---
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running com.cdt.producer.ContractVerifierTest
00:03:39.986 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate from class [org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate]
00:03:39.996 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating BootstrapContext using constructor [public org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultBootstrapContext(java.lang.Class,org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate)]
00:03:40.034 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating TestContextBootstrapper for test class [com.cdt.producer.ContractVerifierTest] from class [org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper]
00:03:40.057 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Neither @ContextConfiguration nor @ContextHierarchy found for test class [com.cdt.producer.ContractVerifierTest], using SpringBootContextLoader
00:03:40.063 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Did not detect default resource location for test class [com.cdt.producer.ContractVerifierTest]: class path resource [com/cdt/producer/ContractVerifierTest-context.xml] does not exist
00:03:40.064 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Did not detect default resource location for test class [com.cdt.producer.ContractVerifierTest]: class path resource [com/cdt/producer/ContractVerifierTestContext.groovy] does not exist
00:03:40.064 [main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Could not detect default resource locations for test class [com.cdt.producer.ContractVerifierTest]: no resource found for suffixes {-context.xml, Context.groovy}.
00:03:40.065 [main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoaderUtils - Could not detect default configuration classes for test class [com.cdt.producer.ContractVerifierTest]: ContractVerifierTest does not declare any static, non-private, non-final, nested classes annotated with @Configuration.
00:03:40.128 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.ActiveProfilesUtils - Could not find an 'annotation declaring class' for annotation type [org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles] and class [com.cdt.producer.ContractVerifierTest]
00:03:40.191 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider - Identified candidate component class: file [/Users/nodirbekusmanov/workspace/poc-consumer/2/producer/target/classes/com/cdt/producer/ProducerApplication.class]
00:03:40.191 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Found @SpringBootConfiguration com.cdt.producer.ProducerApplication for test class com.cdt.producer.ContractVerifierTest
00:03:40.293 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - @TestExecutionListeners is not present for class [com.cdt.producer.ContractVerifierTest]: using defaults.
00:03:40.294 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Loaded default TestExecutionListener class names from location [META-INF/spring.factories]: [org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.RestDocsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.event.EventPublishingTestExecutionListener]
00:03:40.315 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Using TestExecutionListeners: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@77d2e85, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener@3ecd267f, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener@58ffcbd7, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@555cf22, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener@6bb2d00b, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener@3c9bfddc, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener@1a9c38eb, org.springframework.test.context.event.EventPublishingTestExecutionListener@319bc845, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener@4c5474f5, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.RestDocsTestExecutionListener@2f4205be, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener@54e22bdd, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener@3bd418e4, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverTestExecutionListener@544820b7]
00:03:40.320 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDirtiesContextTestExecutionListener - Before test class: context [DefaultTestContext@aafcffa testClass = ContractVerifierTest, testInstance = [null], testMethod = [null], testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [WebMergedContextConfiguration@6955cb39 testClass = ContractVerifierTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.cdt.producer.ProducerApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[[ImportsContextCustomizer@235a0c16 key = [org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.stream.ContractVerifierStreamAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.integration.ContractVerifierIntegrationConfiguration, org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.amqp.ContractVerifierAmqpAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.amqp.RabbitMockConnectionFactoryAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.camel.ContractVerifierCamelConfiguration, org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.jms.ContractVerifierJmsConfiguration, org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.kafka.ContractVerifierKafkaConfiguration, org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.noop.NoOpContractVerifierAutoConfiguration]], org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@5e21e98f, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@72ade7e3, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@3224a577, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@420a85c4, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestArgs@1], resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map['org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.activateListener' -> true]], class annotated with @DirtiesContext [false] with mode [null].
00:03:40.371 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.TestPropertySourceUtils - Adding inlined properties to environment: {spring.jmx.enabled=false, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true, server.port=-1}

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.7.RELEASE)

2020-05-23 00:03:40.739  INFO 9559 --- [           main] com.cdt.producer.ContractVerifierTest    : Starting ContractVerifierTest on CFC02XL862JG5H with PID 9559 (started by nodirbekusmanov in /Users/nodirbekusmanov/workspace/poc-consumer/2/producer)
2020-05-23 00:03:40.741  INFO 9559 --- [           main] com.cdt.producer.ContractVerifierTest    : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-05-23 00:03:42.501  INFO 9559 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-05-23 00:03:42.835  INFO 9559 --- [           main] com.cdt.producer.ContractVerifierTest    : Started ContractVerifierTest in 2.453 seconds (JVM running for 3.49)
2020-05-23 00:03:43.231  INFO 9559 --- [           main] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [localhost:5672]
2020-05-23 00:03:43.304  INFO 9559 --- [           main] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Created new connection: rabbitConnectionFactory#3850e90c:0/SimpleConnection@1d7f2f0a [delegate=amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/, localPort= 55164]
2020-05-23 00:03:43.339 ERROR 9559 --- [           main] .c.c.v.m.i.SpringIntegrationStubMessages : Exception occurred while trying to read a message from  a channel with name [user-presence]

org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'user-presence' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:814) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1282) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:297) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:207) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1114) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.integration.SpringIntegrationStubMessages.receive(SpringIntegrationStubMessages.java:70) ~[spring-cloud-contract-verifier-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.integration.SpringIntegrationStubMessages.receive(SpringIntegrationStubMessages.java:83) ~[spring-cloud-contract-verifier-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.integration.SpringIntegrationStubMessages.receive(SpringIntegrationStubMessages.java:35) ~[spring-cloud-contract-verifier-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.internal.ContractVerifierMessaging.receive(ContractVerifierMessaging.java:44) ~[spring-cloud-contract-verifier-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at com.cdt.producer.ContractVerifierTest.validate_user_presence(ContractVerifierTest.java:30) ~[test-classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:675) ~[junit-platform-commons-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:125) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:132) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:124) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:74) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:104) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:62) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:43) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:35) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:202) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:198) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:69) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:220) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:188) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:202) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:181) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invokeAllTests(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:150) ~[surefire-junit-platform-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invoke(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:124) ~[surefire-junit-platform-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:384) ~[surefire-booter-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:345) ~[surefire-booter-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:126) ~[surefire-booter-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:418) ~[surefire-booter-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]

[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 3.465 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.cdt.producer.ContractVerifierTest
[ERROR] validate_user_presence  Time elapsed: 0.516 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'user-presence' available
    at com.cdt.producer.ContractVerifierTest.validate_user_presence(ContractVerifierTest.java:30)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'user-presence' available
    at com.cdt.producer.ContractVerifierTest.validate_user_presence(ContractVerifierTest.java:30)

2020-05-23 00:03:43.410  INFO 9559 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
[INFO]
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[ERROR] Errors:
[ERROR]   ContractVerifierTest.validate_user_presence:30 » IllegalState org.springframew...
[INFO]
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  10.182 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-05-23T00:03:43+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) on project producer: There are test failures.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please refer to /Users/nodirbekusmanov/workspace/poc-consumer/2/producer/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: i had a syntax failure in yml for enabling the stubrunner - properties syntax in yml file:
https://github.com/nusmanov/producer/commit/0c44618da1a9ce7f039e1684cf9078e67cc63b26